# Trying to execute SASS from PHP via exec() function

Tags: php, ruby, rubygems, exec, sass

I have a site with color settings in the admin. You change your colors, it saves a .scss file and runs exec('sass file.scss file.css'). Works fine locally (on MAMP), but fails on server. First, I turned off safe mode. Second, I checked, using exec(), to see if it had access to the anything. It did, but when running sass --help, sass -v, or anything with sass, no output was returned.

Anyone do this before or know what could be causing it? I'm running on Media Temple, if that helps.

Comment: Try using the second and third arguments to `exec()` to get some info on what is going wrong, post it back here if you don't understand.

Comment: First argument returns
`Array
(
)`
Second returns:
`126`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) Do you have `sass` installed on the target server?
b) Is the `sass` executable in your `PATH`?
c) See here for the meanings of exit codes
http://en.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html

```
126: Permission problem or command is not an executable
```

Comment: a) SASS is installed and I can run the command from SSH perfectly. b) Honestly don't know what this means. c) That helps a lot in explaining what is happening. What's the fix?

Comment: If it helps, I installed SASS and Ruby while logged in as root.

Comment: @James - In SSH run the command `which sass`, this will show the full path to sass. Something like `/xyz/abc/bin/sass`. Then use this full path in your `exec` call. Although I suspect something else is wrong, but it's worth a try..

Comment: This line fixed it: `putenv("PATH=/usr/local/bin");` Thanks for the help!